# Best Practice - Building a query based on user selections

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I am creating a small web based tool that allows users to query a large lookup table in various ways. Since its a small tool, I'm using JSP/Servlets.

The lookup table has a definition something like this:

column1 | column2 | column3 | date | user | count

The user can query by column values or a range. Also, the results can be sorted by a specific column. Because the table has several hundred thousand of records, and growing rapidly, I'm using Oracle's ROWNUM and only returning a small subset of results.

I have a form page that gets the search criteria from the user. I generate my query based on a series of conditions, for example:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=1 "
if(searchCriteria1 != "")
    query += "AND column1='searchCriteria1' "
if(searchCriteria2 != "")
    query += "AND column2='searchCriteria2' "
if(searchCriteria2 != "")
    query += "AND column2='searchCriteria2' "
if(searchCriteria3 != "")
    query += "AND column3='searchCriteria3' "
if((searchCriteria4 != "") && (searchCriteria5 != ""))
    query += "AND date>='searchCriteria4' AND date<='searchCriteria5' "
etc...
```

(This is just simplified pseudo code)

The sorting is handled after the first results page is displayed. The user clicks on the column header of that page to sort by that column. This would be doing a post back and querying the database. Basically, I run the same code above but with this at the end:

```
if(sortColumn1)
    query += "ORDER BY column1"
if(sortColumn2)
    query += "ORDER BY column2"
if(sortColumn3)
    query += "ORDER BY column3"
```

So, as you might imagine, my query building code is very long with all these different conditions. Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Comment: Why cant you sort on the client side using jquery? or any of the other js plugins

Comment: First of all, I don't think you need to return everything fit the criteria, you only need to return top 100 or even less. Secondly, is it possible to split the large look up table into several small tables, cos I think for some columns, their chances of being searched is much higher than the others, by spliting them and joining them back together at a proper time later can increase the performance. Thirdly, you dont have to do all the sorting in server side i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation is not the best choice for SQL. The best you can do is to use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) or [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) and do it in the OO way. I am more familiar with QueryDSL. Look at the examples [here](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html).

```
SQLQuery query = new SQLQueryImpl(connection, dialect); 
query.from(myTable);

BooleanBuilder wheres = new BooleanBuilder();

if(notBlank(searchCriteria1))
   wheres.and(myTable.column1.eq(searchCriteria1));
if(notBlank(searchCriteria2))
   wheres.and(myTable.column2.eq(searchCriteria2));
if(notBlank(searchCriteria4) && notBlank(searchCriteria5))
   wheres.andAllOf(myTable.date.goe(searchCriteria4),  myTable.date.loe(searchCriteria5));  //you may want to use myTable.date.between(...)

if (...) {
   query.orderBy(myTable.column1.asc());
} else if (...){
   query.orderBy(myTable.column2.asc());
}

query.limit(100); //it is good to limit a result
query.list(myTable.all());
```

As for SQL injection query engine will wrap your arguments in named parameters while constructing SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, do not use a simple `String` for your query.  You should go with the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), which protects you against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (a very easy way for malicious users to disrupt vulnerable systems).

Secondly, there won't be much you can do to avoid the `if()... else if()...` blocks if your input really is that complex.  It almost looks like your method is doing much more than it should.  Consider calling different methods based on the type of query your user wants to run.  I've implemented many DAOs, and there's no way to get around all those null checks in your `if` blocks when it comes to adding `AND` lines to your `WHERE` clause.

One thing you can definitely do, though, is write most of the query in a `private static final String` constant with question marks where you want your parameters to be (`?`), append the other criteria you need based on the user input, and construct your `PreparedStatement` directly from that.  Once you've made the `PreparedStatement`, you can use the various setter commands to have it fill in those `?`s.  This tidies up the code quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever, ever put user entered data into your query using string concatenation.  You should use named parameters or positional parameters in your query and pass the parameters.

Comment: ye. I've been Sql injected once which is a shame experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think sending requests to backend to do sorting is not a great idea. There are plenty of plugins in js to sort a table,which can be used.

Comment: Sort several hundred thousand rows using javascript?  He's going to have to do a callback for the sorted results.

Comment: No what I meant is that, once he gets back some results, there is no further needed to make a request to backend to order by different columns within that set of results. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What if the number of results he gets back is 10,000 items long? It would be very bad to send the entire result set back to a table on the client and rely on javascript to sort them.  He's going to need paginated results, which means a round trip to the server for each new page, and a round trip to the server to get the new page if the sort field is changed.

Answer (score 0):

From a simplistic perspective

If you know all the columns that types you can use arrays and tables to make this code more data driven.